# earnest vs earnesty vs earnestness

Tags: phrases

I have come across all these phrases

- in all earnest
- in all earnesty
- in all earnestness

Is it ok to use any of them?

Example sentence with the first version:
*I intend to complete my assigned tasks in all earnest*

Comment: I do not recall hearing any of those phrases. ‘In all honesty’ is a common phrase, and so is ‘in earnest’ (though neither would fit your example sentence semantically), and it would be very simple for someone to get them mixed up and start saying ‘in all earnest(y)’. If Google is anything to go by, ‘in all earnestness’ is more common and perhaps less of a conglobulation, but I can’t say I’d ever say it myself. Sounds clumsy to my ear.

Comment: I think "in all sincerity" could be a good replacement in the example sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Earnestness](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/earnestness) is a noun (according to Dictionary.com), so *in all earnestness* works.  I have, in fact, said that very phrase in the past.

[Earnesty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/earnesty) doesn't seem to be a word, insofar as it is not found in the same dictionary, and [earnest](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/earnest), in the sense you're using it here, is an adjective.

Comment: _Earnest_ does exist as a (rather rare) noun, but with a different meaning, given by the OED as "Money, or a sum of money, paid as an instalment, esp. for the purpose of securing a bargain or contract. Also fig. A foretaste, instalment, pledge, of anything afterwards to be received in greater abundance. †Phrase, _on_ (_in_, _for_) _earnest_ : by way of earnest, as an instalment or foretaste." The more common meaning of _in earnest_ is an adverbial use like _in short_, not a noun.

Comment: Ah yes, a good point. I'll update my answer.

Comment: _Earnesty_ is also given in the OED as an obsolete synonym of "earnestness".

Answer (score -2):

Not a word, because few if any dictionaries include it.

'Earnest' is an adjective. 
'Earnest' can be a noun, but with definite limits.
'Earnestness' is a word whose meaning cannot be misconstrued, but is almost too much of a mouthful. 
'Earnesty' should be a noun and if enough people use it as a noun, that should do it.

Why not?

Illiterates let 'dilemma' do for ANY problem just a plain question. 
They pull out 'issue' when 'problem', 'matter', 'concern', 'challenge', 'worry', or 'point-of-contention' would let let others know WTF was meant. It's as bad as 'like' for other word.

So champion a word, when the need for it is very real. Why let educated and uneducated illiterates shape the language?

Comment: Mouthful? The Constantinopolitans wouldn't think so.